# "Be one of the first 10 applicants" may not be sending the right message to job seekers

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

I want to provide a bit of feedback on a new feature I've seen on Jobs in the last few days.

I've noticed there is a new indicator on some Job postings. It is a notice under the tags associated with the job indicating you can be one of the first 10 applicants

[image: Be one of the first 10 applicants]

At first this seemed like a good idea and a way to determine the competition level for the position. However, after visiting jobs a few times and seeing it in action, I've found myself ignoring some of these postings and instead wondering "what's wrong with this posting"

Here's an example of a recent search I performed. Notice that all of these jobs are less than two hours old:

[image: Newest Jobs]

In this listing of newest jobs, there are three that have (presumably) had less than 10 applicants already. Great for Stack Exchange and the other companies that are posting here! But, I find myself wondering: "What's wrong with these companies that they can't draw applicants when others posted at the same time can?"

So, I ignore those posts.

---

I don't think it's your intention that we should ignore these postings. I'd guess that you would much rather me view these as I did initially ("Look, less competition and a newer posting, I should take a look"). I can't seem to shake the feeling that these feel "damaged" some how though, especially when there are postings that have a "<1h ago" time stamp that are not getting this notice and a post that is hours old still has a "be one of the first!" notice.

What is the goal of these new indicator?

Comment: It can just as well go the other way: if a position has gotten 10+ responses in under an hour, maybe it's a feeding frenzy and you don't want to deal with that much competition.

Comment: And for a different angle, I'm seeing this indicator on positions that messaged me unsolicited several *months* ago. If a position hasn't gotten 10 responses in that much time, something is probably wrong with it. Bottom line, there is no upside for this flag. Only downside.

Comment: well, technically... this is measuring *applications*. So it doesn't matter how many responses they received. If they didn't get 10 people to apply, then this badge will appear on the job.

Comment: Why does "first 10 applicants" matter for software development jobs in this day and age? Did [Charlie Chaplin design this new feature](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nA6EGpUZsKQ&t=1h15m19s)? :P

Comment: I was using "responses" generically. Either way it's bad.

Comment: You argue this should be removed because it "hurts" the offer, but I don't think so, meaning I don't think it should be removed. It's an objective measure. For some, it will be something that makes them click; for others it will be a red flag. So... what? *A fact is a fact is a fact.*

Comment: @xDaizu Facts without context invite subjective interpretation. Consider a listing that has generated 7 applications. I'd have a much different impression of the job if I knew whether those applications came from a pool of 9 vs 9000 potential applicants.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Thanks for your invaluable feedback. That is a feature we're testing right now, exactly to see how having a badge affects the apply rate.

Our hypothesis is that seeing the badge in a job would make it more appealing to candidates, as a "signal" that they may have a better chance than with a listing that received hundreds of applicants.

There are a few caveats though:

- We don't have visibility into what happens on listings that link to an external site, so those jobs aren't eligible for getting the badge.
- Listings that use an external ATSs (application tracking systems) aren't eligible for the badge either.

That's why lots of really fresh jobs don't have the badge, just because they weren't eligible in the first place.

We have plans to improve the badge if we graduate the experiment (meaning: including listings that use external ATSs and estimating the amount of applicants based on the clicks they've received).

I personally never realized how this badge could actually hurt the quality perception of a listing, and your point makes a whole lot of sense.

Again, thanks for sharing your thoughts.

Comment: I think that if you can't track external variables, I think you should flip the badge: this job had more than 10 applicants. I know it's a negative reinforcement (+10 applicants means that there's heavy competency for the job, so I wouldn't apply) but at least it could funnel users to jobs without that many applicants. Alternatively, you could show that you don't have stats of how many supplicants an offer has.

Comment: Maybe signal something like "This is new job, be one of the first to apply" to make it clear that there's nothing wrong with few applications?