# Stack Overflow Jobs Update - June 2 2017

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

We've got a few updates on [Stack Overflow Jobs](https://www.stackoverflow.com/jobs/?utm_source=so-owned&utm_medium=meta&utm_content=Jobs_update_2_June) that we want to let you know about.

#### Better synonyms

[Aurélien](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1370722/aur%C3%A9lien-gasser) recently improved our list of synonyms to give you more accurate results. For instance, [angular.js](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?sort=i&q=angular.js), [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?sort=i&q=angularjs) and [angular js](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?sort=i&q=angular+js) now give identical results.

Additionally, we introduced new synonyms after analyzing searches on Jobs – they include "customer service", "cto", "intern", "junior" and their variants. In total, more than 200 new terms are recognized more accurately.

#### Tighter sidebar & UX

[image]

[Kirti](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1012097/kirti-thorat) and [Donna](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4406529/donna) added fit and finish on the UI, such as the sidebar & apply button above, and arranged elements to be more accessible. Mobile too!

#### Better signals

From [Gervasio](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/920295/g3rv4): Our user research and [the community](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349116/job-advertisers-that-dont-respond-to-applications-and-questions) (that’s you) showed that some employers are more responsive than others. We also learned that applicants would like to have an idea of how much competition they will have.

You'll notice new icons: one for [employers that respond well](http://stackoverflow.com/jobs?b=HighResponse) and one to indicate when you will be [one of the early applicants](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?b=FirstApplicants).

#### No/Few results

Finally, from [Andrew](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/239394/andrew): when a search returns no or few results, we now display a new section which includes [jobs we think might interest you](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?sort=i&q=dsfsdfsd&l=London%2C+United+Kingdom&d=20&u=Miles).

Feedback always welcome. We'll make a habit of these Meta updates too!

Answer (score 11):

Thank you for taking into consideration feedback I [provided](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/345817/189134) while you were testing one of the signals. I like the "Be one of the first applicants" better. I can provide more feedback as I continue to use it, but I don't see as many of these badges as I did before. That's a good thing and will hopefully draw my attention to those postings instead of make me concerned about them.

I do have a bit of feedback though. I noticed the "High Response Rate" badge early today, before seeing this meta post and immediately thought that it meant a "high number of users have applied", not that the company responds to users. The lack of a tooltip on either badge doesn't help. The way the badge is worded doesn't imply that you are saying good things about the company. It implies the user has a lot of competition if they apply to this posting.

Second, both of the links you provided to test the new badges added a recent search in my Recent Searches box. But, they both appear like so:

[image: New badges]

Can this be clarified so that we know which is which?

Comment: Thank you for your continued amazing feedback :) you are right, your thoughtful post helped us better target the be one of the first applicants icon. We'll definitely revise the wording (and the need of a tooltip) and I'll make sure I fix the text on the recent searches. Keep it coming!

Comment: The issue on the recent searches is fixed now. Thanks!

Comment: The `High Response Rate` badge is still confusing and I reacted in exactly the same as way as Andy did - same initial thoughts and then trying to find the non-existent tooltip. Searching for the answer landed me here.