# Don't automatically create a recent search in Jobs

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Please don't automatically save recent searches in Jobs. With the limited number of previous searches that are saved (4), if I want to search for a specific company one day, or if I click on links in [recent announcements](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350148/jobs-update-2-june), my saved searches that I use are overwritten.

I have set up 4 searches. I use those to look for positions in a specific geographic area, remote positions, remote positions above a specific salary and a set of jobs that match specific key words. If I see a job ad on the main site and want to look up that company, when I do so, I lose one of the searches I want to keep. If I want to perform a random search to see if there are jobs that match another technology or are in another region as one off searches, I lose one of the searches I want to keep.

Please don't save searches by default. Give me a way to save the search at the expense of my oldest unused search (like today), but don't automatically remove searches that I have set up because I performed a one off search or worse, clicked on a link that took me to the job search page.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. This has come up a few times and we're looking into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature has been updated. Instead of storing your recent searches, you can save the searches you want to keep around.

[image: save a search]

Saved searches will appear in the right hand side bar.

[image: saved search]

Answer (score 1):

The idea of that section is to provide a "history" of what you've been checking out, so every time you perform a search (either by explicitly searching or by clicking on a url) it's saved.

However, it sounds like you're using it more like "favorite searches", right?

We don't currently have anything like that (and it sounds like a useful feature) but there're 2 workarounds that could help you:

- Create an alert. You would then get an email when new jobs matching your particular searches get added into the board.
- Bookmark your favorite searches (each search has its parameters on the url, so if you bookmark those pages, you have an easy way of accessing them). The disadvantage of this method is that you don't get to see how many new jobs were added into your search.

Comment: *"it sounds like you're using it more like "favorite searches", right?"* - That's exactly how I'm using it. It's especially useful when it shows the number of new jobs that appear before I click on the link.