# Stop automatically performing a search based on my location in jobs

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

For the past few days, when I click on the jobs link, one of my recent searches has been replaced with "jobs in Illinois (within 20 miles)".

It took me a while to figure out what was happening. It also happens if I manually type `https://stackoverflow.com/jobs` in the url bar. It changes the link to `https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/developer-jobs-in-illinois`. This new url seems to happen with a new browser session, not on each refresh.

*Stop doing this.*

For one, it over writes my searches. This is completely unexpected behavior. I didn't perform this search. I didn't want to perform this search. Yet, it happened and it removed a search I did want to save.

Related request to stop this behavior: [Don't automatically create a recent search in Jobs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350166/dont-automatically-create-a-recent-search-in-jobs)

Second, "within 20 miles" is not helpful when you are searching an entire state.

Comment: I hope it does not happen on non-USA countries.. there's quite a few where 20 miles is ridiculously short distance (Africa or Australia, anyone?). I myself wouldn't find a job offer from my current company with such distance limit, and it takes me 0 (remote work) to 20 minutes (suburb train) to get there (one way, x2 for total) = not ridiculous, but pretty quick.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl with a VPN outside USA, it does happen (I tried with Singapore). Well, for me everything is defaulting to "20 km" instead of "20 miles" for some reason.

Comment: Australia here. I get the behaviour in the "recent searches" (except that it's "within 20km" not miles), but not the URL change. And yeah, 20km is pretty short - Melbourne is close to 100km across at its widest, and there are plenty of people who commute 30 or more km to the city centre. As well as quite a few tech jobs just over 20km away in the southeast.

Comment: "within 20 km" [in China](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/developer-jobs-in-china) returns jobs in Beijing, Shanghai, Hangzhou, and Wuhan. I guess its correct that all of those jobs are within 20 km of China.

Comment: Only job search I've done that's been that...lenient...is...actually I think I have two. One is "within 20 miles of the US" because I want every job in the US under a specific category and I had to specify a distance. The other one I have is literally "give me everything, anywhere" (only one or two jobs get posted a week even under that wide of a filter and its comforting to see alerts for jobs I don't want than no alerts at all). Within 20 miles of a state is an...odd delineation.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is because we were running an A/B test and you were on the B side of the experiment. Results indicate that it wasn't successful so I've disabled it and pushed to production. Apologies for the inconvenience!

Comment: There seem to be a couple other A/B tests running right now that we're on the B side of: US politics, Brexit, several others. Plz disable and push to production, too. Thx!

Comment: @Pekka웃 I think we're working on the US one. It will take some time to pass through code review, but even if it takes a year, it'll still be the fastest it's ever been done.