# Do not create recent searches for intermediate search steps in Jobs

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

When I put in search criteria, a "Recent Search" entry should only be created when I am done putting in criteria.

Currently the system creates a recent search for each sub-step in the process:

- I type "Python" in the first box and either press `tab` or click in the Location box
- A recent search entry is created - over writing a recent search and a search is performed for only "Python" jobs.
- I type in "Chicago" and press `tab`
- A recent search entry is created - over writing another recent search and a search is performed for Python jobs in Chicago with a 20 mile radius.
- I change the default "20 miles" to "50 miles"
- A recent entry is created - over writing *another* recent search and a search is performed for Python jobs in Chicago with a 50 mile radius.
- I click the slider bars icon and entry that I want a minimum salary
- A recent search entry is created and the search is performed for Python jobs in Chicago with a 50 mile radius and a minimum salary.

---

This process has created 4 recent searches and performed several intermediate searches that I ignored. *Why?* I don't need recent searches for those intermediate steps. ([I really don't want you to create recent searches unless I say so, but that was another feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350166/dont-automatically-create-a-recent-search-in-jobs))

Recent searches should not be created for intermediate search criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is on our backlog and we're exploring solutions for this feature. Thanks for the feedback!

**Update**: this feature was updated to "saved searches" (answered [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366513/5516513)).