# Why does Jobs save my cover letter between applications, but not my preferred skills in search?

Tags: discussion, status-deferred, stack-overflow-jobs

This seems completely backwards - I want to craft a unique cover letter for each application, but I'd like to be able to run the same search day after day!

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for your feedback.

Explicitly saving searches in the Jobs user interface is on our radar, but it's not the very next project on our list.  So, I'll be marking this one [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred).  In the meantime, two options that might help you:

1. The "Recent Searches" sidebar should show the last four searches you have run.  Of course, if you use more than four searches on a daily basis, this feature is less useful.  Also, we are aware that Recent Searches [might save unwanted searches](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/350962/239394), another issue that's on our radar.
2. You can create a Job Alert and have your search results sent to you by email.  Once you have performed the search you want, click the "Create Alert" button as shown and follow the prompts.

[image: Create Alert button]

Thanks again for your feedback, as it helps us know what to prioritize.

Comment: Thanks; that helps! Any news on the cover letters?

Comment: @ekolis Applicants who change their cover letters for each job application are in the minority, and about one-fourth of applicants never change their cover letters when applying to multiple jobs.  We used to avoid re-populating the cover letter on subsequent applications, but we changed that decision in part due to the data I just cited.  Perhaps we can look at a better user experience than requiring deleting the entire cover letter manually for users who wish to craft unique cover letters, but it's probably further away than a saved-searches feature.